# Wake up the app when there are changes in specific external storage folder in the background

Tags: android, android-service, android-workmanager, android-alarms, android-storage

I want to track **changes** to the user's selected external storage **folder** in the background **without** **Foreground Service** and **wake up** the app **when** the **changes** **occur**. This **should work** even **if** the user **removes** the app **from** **recent apps**. By waking up the app at this stage I mean to just **send** user a **notification** that the changes were detected. The reason I **don't want** to **use** **Foreground Service** is because I **don't want** to **show** a **constant notification** that I'm monitoring the filesystem.

I thought it wouldn't be possible with current Android restrictions, but then I ran into
[FolderSync](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=dk.tacit.android.foldersync.lite) app. With this app when you set up a local - remote folder pair, it **tracks** the **changes** to the local folder very accurately while **not showing any notification** in the status bar (meaning they are **not** **running** a **Foreground** **Service** to perform that). Please take a look at **[this video](https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/49668442/224467477-b87f0f67-88ad-4519-a0fa-7ea241de7f9d.mp4)** to see how it works (it's shot on a Samsung phone running Android 13)

I've looked into various approaches, and the only potential solution I found is to use [addContentUriTrigger](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/work/Constraints.Builder#addContentUriTrigger(android.net.Uri,kotlin.Boolean)) that **WorkManager** offers.

An example usage in my scenario would be:

```
                val folderUri = Uri.parse("file://" + folderPath)

                workRequestBuilder.setConstraints(
                    Constraints.Builder()
                        .addContentUriTrigger(folderUri, true)
                        .build()
                ).addTag(WORKER_TAG)

                workManager.enqueue(syncMonitorBuilder.build())
```

But it **doesn't work**. First, in this case, for some reason WorkManager doesn't get triggered at all. And if I replace it with `.addContentUriTrigger(MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, true)` to listen to the **changes** of **DCIM** directory (instead of a custom directory) - WorkManager **works** fine while the app in recent apps, but **stops** once you **remove** the app **from** **recent** **apps**.

Answer (score 1):

I have installed [FolderSync](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=dk.tacit.android.foldersync.lite) in an Android (API level 33) emulator. Then I have set it up to sync files from local `folder1` to local `folder2`. I then removed it from recent apps and saw this on logcat:

```
03-16 17:50:52.285   602   634 I ActivityManager: Start proc 14853:dk.tacit.android.foldersync.lite/u0a167 for broadcast {dk.tacit.android.foldersync.lite/dk.tacit.android.foldersync.receivers.ScheduleAlarmReceiver}
03-16 17:50:52.630   602  2208 W ActivityManager: Background start not allowed: service Intent { act=dk.tacit.android.foldersync.FOREGROUND cmp=dk.tacit.android.foldersync.lite/dk.tacit.android.foldersync.services.SyncService } to dk.tacit.android.foldersync.lite/dk.tacit.android.foldersync.services.SyncService from pid=14853 uid=10167 pkg=dk.tacit.android.foldersync.lite startFg?=false
```

The last line repeats every ~10Min.

As you can see on the names `ScheduleAlarmReceiver` and `SyncService` it seems to use [AlarmManager](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager) and a [sync adapter](https://developer.android.com/training/sync-adapters/creating-sync-adapter) to wake up from sleep. Because I know both can be used to wake up an app I am quite sure these two are used.

The AlarmManager can wake up your app every 10 mins for example (see [setRepeating()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager#setRepeating(int,%20long,%20long,%20android.app.PendingIntent)) and [setInexactRepeating()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager#setInexactRepeating(int,%20long,%20long,%20android.app.PendingIntent))).

If you use a sync adapter there is an account for your app under Settings > Accounts (smiliar to an email account). It can also wake up your app periodically.

In the logcat you can also see it tries to create a foreground service. But this is blocked because the app is in the background. As you can see even FolderSync uses a foreground service.

I waited one hour and the app was not killed. I assume FolderSync is never killed again after restarted by the AlarmManager on AOSP. You can read on [dontkillmyapp.com](https://dontkillmyapp.com) that there is no problem about background apps being killed on AOSP.

But on Samsung for example FolderSync will be killed soon again after it's been woken up. It may happen that 30 seconds after being woken up FolderSync is killed again. So waking up your app doesn't fix the problem because it will get killed soon again.

You've faced a problem many Android programmers hate. Questions similar to "How to prevent my app from being killed?" have been asked many many times on stackoverflow. But as dontkillmyapp.com explains it comes from the manufactures and not Android itself.

Sometimes there are battery settings (might depend on the manufacturer) which eventually prevent your app from being killed. It's explained on dontkillmyapp.com.

I recommand to use a foreground service. The fact that apps like [WhatsApp](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.whatsapp) (part of Meta/Facebook) use a foreground service to check for messages shows that this is how it's done. There is no other secret way to prevent your app from being killed. Also it doesn't bother most people if there is a small symbol in the title bar. WhatsApp for example starts the foreground service and when the work is done it ends the foreground service. So you won't see it all the time.

You can use AlaramManager to wake up periodically. You can also create an account (which appears under Settings > Accounts) to wake up you app periodically. Or you can send a message to your app using Google cloud messages. There are many other broadcasts like "device booting" or "screen turned on" which can all wake up your app. But as already said it can get killed again soon without a foreground service.

I want to add that when you root your device it is possible to keep your app running in the background without a foreground service.

Comment: Thank you for such a detailed response. Just to clarify, during your testing, in the folder pair settings -> advanced tab did you activate the Instant Sync option?

Comment: @konnovdev I now enabled instant sync but it didn't sync instantly. It still took 5min. I think WorkManager is the right way. You can also try to use Linux inotify natively. Also read this https://stackoverflow.com/a/53582224/11016652 WorkManager can perhaps wake up your device but as already said you need a foreground service so the app doesn't get killed again and there is no other option.

Comment: hey @zomega, I've had a chat with FolderSync author and it turned out everything was much less sophisticated than we thought. He was just using a background service, see my answer below. I was frankly quite shocked as I didn't even realize that current Android versions allow you to continue running the background service when you close the app. Nonetheless I think you did a good research with your answer, thank you putting your time into that, I think your bounty award is well deserved.

Answer (score 0):

So I contacted the FolderSync developer. And it turned out everything was very simple: he was using a plain old Background Service. But he opted for disabling battery optimizations (see *[android.permission.REQUEST_IGNORE_BATTERY_OPTIMIZATIONS](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission#REQUEST_IGNORE_BATTERY_OPTIMIZATIONS)* permission), which requires approval from Google Play. He does not use Work Manager or Alarm Manager for this feature.

So I tried this approach and it works like a charm! I'm happy with this solution. If in future Google disallows running Background Services - then I'll just switch to Foreground Service (which would require a very small code change).